# Store a function's help in a variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, documentation, printf

I want to create an html file to print a handout with all the functions in one folder. Is there a way to programmatically access each functions' help in order to prepare a string input?

I was thinking something along the lines of the fictitious `getfunchelp()` in a program like this:

```
Functions=dir('*.m');

fid = fopen('FunctionSummary.htm','a');
fprintf(fid, ['<HTML><HEAD><TITLE> Function Summary </TITLE>\n']);

for ii=1:length(Functions)

   FunctionName=Functions(ii).name;
   FunctionHelp=getfunchelp(FunctionName); % <= This one over here

   fprintf(fid, ['<H2>',FunctionName,'</H2>']);
   fprintf(fid, ['\n<BR><i>',FunctionHelp,'</i> ']); 
    %... 

end

 fclose(fid);
```

Or is there a better way to do this? (can `publish()` achieve this easier without printing the rest of the function code?)

Comment: It depends on how the function help is defined. There are 2 ways. One of them is basically the first N lines with a `%`. This creates functions with help with a very "basic" formatting. The other one is `html` formatting (like MATLAB's inbuilt function have). Reading the first one is as easy as opening the .m files and reading lines util one has not an initial `%`. The second one may be more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, this works too, but I am happy to discover that bit about help()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the output of [`help`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/help.html) to provide the text-version of the function's documentation

```
helpstr = help(Functions(ii).name);
```

It may also be worth looking into [custom documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-custom-documentation.html) because there are lots of methods already built into MATLAB for displaying help for a series of functions in a nice clean way.

Comment: It was that simple and I didn't realize it... in my defense I did try looking for `help help` and saw nothing about it having an output value :D Thanks

Comment: @McMa Yea, it's not explicit in the documentation unfortunately.